# Constrained Horn Clauses vs. "ordinary" Horn Clauses

Tags: logic, constraint-programming, logic-programming

I see why ordinary Horn clauses (of the type Prolog might accept) are first order eg something like (with all variables universally quantified)
$$
P(x) \leftarrow Q_1(x),Q_2(x,y).\\
P(x) \leftarrow Q_2(x,y),P(y).\\
$$
(I'm using the conventional notation of upper case for constants and lower case for variables, rather than Prolog's confusing opposite notation). Given some facts, and a query clause (e.g. $P(x)?$), a Prolog type solver can then return a solution for the variables in the query. However when it comes to Constrained Horn Clauses (eg https://arieg.bitbucket.io/pdf/2022_cav.pdf and https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/hunt/FMCAD/FMCAD18/papers/paper59.pdf) I don't see why they are called first order. It seems to me they ought to be written as second order clauses of the form
$$
p(x) \leftarrow Q_1(x),Q_2(x,y).\\
p(x) \leftarrow Q_2(x,y),p(y).\\
$$
Because the solver is trying to find solutions for the predicate variable $p$ in terms of some underlying theory.

On a related note, my understanding is that recursive Horn clauses (of either type) are not considered to be definitions in a first order *theory* since they don't provide a closed-form definition for the predicate symbols. And that instead we have to introduce a second order operator $\mu$ called the fixpoint operator (and that solvers like muZe in Z3 can handle such operators). Can someone comment on the status of this operator, and if it is indeed second order?

Comment: On page 4 of the bitbucket paper, he defines very precisely with his constrained Horn clauses are. They are definitely first-order, since the quantification is allowed only over variables, not predicates at all. As for the fixpoint operator, I could find no mention of the term “fixpoint” in either paper by searching.

Comment: I don't see the absence of quantification over the predicate symbols as making it first order. Quantifier free or skolemized first order formulas are still first order. To me it has to do with interpretation of the variables - are they interpreted as domain elements, sets of domain elements, sets of sets of domain elements, etc. And in the example I gave above, the variable $p$ is interpreted as a predicate, ie a set of domain elements.